# What do you call the circular thing on a visor that allows it to go down or up?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is it called a hinge? Because when I look up hinge, I get something that looks completely different:

[image]

So what do you call the thing that let it go up and down? And what do you describe the metallic part that moves because of the hinge? Is there a more generic term? In this case, it's a visor, but what's the generic word for something that moves because of a hinge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, "hinge" doesn't quite fit. This is called a **[pivot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pivot)**:

> a fixed point supporting something that turns or balances

Here's an example sentence from the [Wikipedia page for *armet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armet):

> The typical armet consisted of four pieces: the skull, the two large hinged cheek-pieces which locked at the front over the chin, and a visor which had a double **pivot**, one either side of the skull.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called a hinge, pivot, joint, or articulation. Those all mean basically the same thing, but with slightly different connotations. As you mention, "hinge" is associated with joining things like doors, the top of a chest, etc. While the hinge you found looks different from the pivots on the helmets, it's the same basic structure.